# How does scikit learn differentiate between incoming ndarrays or pandas DataFrame objects?

Tags: python, algorithm, scikit-learn

I'm trying to write a decision tree regression class from scratch. I'm writing it to take its data in NumPy ndarray form. I don't plan on using it for anything but self-teaching, but I got to wondering how scikit-learn so easily handles both simultaneously. I.e. it will fit a model on data that is either an ndarray, a list, or a dataframe/series object.

Is there a simple explanation for such robust handling of many different object types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scikit-Learn was not built to be fit directly on pandas dataframes. Pandas's `df` is converted to numpy arrays internally.

This is explicitly stated in the source code of `DecisionTreeRegressor`:

``` X : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
     The training input samples. Internally, it will be converted to
     ``dtype=np.float32`` and if a sparse matrix is provided
     to a sparse ``csc_matrix``. ```

Source: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e/sklearn/tree/_classes.py#L597

Comment: I don't think that source code says what you're saying.  But the conversion from dataframe to np.ndarray does happen, usually in the input validation of `fit`, via `check_X_y` or `check_array` or similar.